# using mock data while on development with vue + vuex

Tags: vue.js, mocking, vuex

I'm working on a Vue app which also uses vuex.

Everything is setup ad working correctly as expected but i'd like to improve it so that I can work on it without actually calling the API endpoints (mainly to avoid rate limit).

I created a mock folder and placed some file in there.
How do I manage to use those mock in development, and the real api endpoint on the build on production withouth making a mess in my code ?

I created a [repo](https://github.com/koop4/vuetest) with as less as possible.
It includes vue + vuex, a single smart component in charge of reading from the store, and a dumb component do display it.

In poor words, I'm looking for a way to do change this:

```
const actions = {
  async fetchTodos({ commit }) {
    let response;
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      response = { data: todos };
    } else {
      response = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
    }
    commit("setTodos", response.data);
  }
};
```

with something which would be easier to maintain and wouldn't increase the bundle size.

I thought about mocking the whole action object, which seemed to be ok, but how do i avoid to bundle my mock files at that point?

How do you manage your front end environment to avoid this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

What I did is encapsulate the whole API in another class/object. That single point of entry then switches between the mock and real api:

```
// store.js
const api = require('./api');

const actions = {
  async fetchTodos({ commit }) {
    // you can use api.getTodos() instead or another naming convention
    const response = await api.get('todos');
    commit("setTodos", response.data);
  },
};

// api.js
const realapi = require('./realapi');
const mockapi = require('./mockapi');

module.exports = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? realapi : mockapi;


// mockapi/index.js
const todos = loadTodos();

module.exports = {
  async get(path) {
    switch (path) {
      case 'todos':
        return { data: todos };

      // etc.
    }
  }
};

// realapi/index.js
const root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';

module.exports = {
  get(path) {
    return axios.get(root + path);
  }
};
```

Builders like Webpack can optimize the build and remove the whole mock api part in production builds [based on the environment](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-mode).